# How can I make a personal snapshot of my Windows installation?

Tags: windows, backup

I have a necessity to format the drives on my laptop every month and make a fresh installation of Windows. Every time I do this, I have to set all my preferred settings and install all my needed software and set my preferred settings in those software too. It takes a full day of work.

So, let's say I make a fresh install of Win 11, install Visual Studio, VLC, Chrome, Spotify etc. (Just to make a sample case). Then I set all my settings both in Windows and in the various softwares.

At this point I would like to create an **exact copy** of the system so that the next time I format I can simply restore this "copy" and avoid all the time consuming process of tinkering with settings.

Now I'm fully aware of backups, but last time I made a backup (with the windows backup utility) it didn't restore an exact copy of the system, so I think what I need is a snapshot and not a backup. How can I do that? What's the best way to store this snapshot? How do I later use this snapshot to restore the system?

Comment: Look at Norton Ghost or CloneZilla. Do a fresh install, get your system configured how you like it, and then take an image with one of those tools onto a different drive (one not used by Windows or your applications). Then when you're ready to go back to a clean install, just restore the image.

Comment: Norton Ghost hasn’t been updated in more than 2 decades

Comment: @Ramhound because it's awesome, and doesn't need updating :D /s

Comment: @spikey_richie - It also likely cannot image anything larger than a 2 TB drive due to MSDOS environment

Comment: To be fair, I last used it in 2008. I'm not surprised it's defunct.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Windows Backup from the old Windows 7 - use a third-party
product instead.

My favorite product is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).
Use it to take an image of your entire disk. The backup will include
only sectors that were used, so will be of reasonable size.

When the time comes, use AOMEI to restore the disk.

If required, you can use the
[AOMEI Bootable Media](https://www.ubackup.com/help/create-bootable-disk.html)
to boot from USB to restore the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Windows' integrated backup works for this purpose as good as any other. If you have used it and your result was a different system after restore as compared to what you backed up, then I would like to know what differences you saw.
Please note: for domain controllers (the most important PC in a windows network), this is the only supported way of backing them up, so it seems Microsoft has a lot of trust in the built-in method! We use it, no problems.
If you want an alternative, I can recommend http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/down.htm

Comment: When I backed up my old system some softwares were not working properly due to some messed up registry keys. Maybe a faulty backup ? I do not know.